# Compare 2 text files and find the difference in a list and find which list values are not matching

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, compare

I am reading 2 text files(may contain duplicates) using Scanner and writing them to arraylist. I am comparing both the arraylist to find the difference. When I print out I can see what the difference are but I don't know which record is from what file(text file name)

Contents in text1.txt

```
TIMESTAMP,FE,TDI,20190703113119,20190601000000,20190701000000,
TIMESTAMP,FE,KYMI,20190703113130,20190601000000,20190701000000,
TIMESTAMP,FE,UMRI,20190703113154,20190601000000,20190701000000,
TIMESTAMP,FE,MLI,20190703113211,20190601000000,20190701000000,
TIMESTAMP,FE,WOLI,20190703113221,20190601000000,20190701000000,
TIMESTAMP,FE,VEM,20190703113221,20190601000000,20190701000000,
TIMESTAMP,FE,ZER,20190703113154,20190601000000,20190701000000,
```

Contents in text2.txt

```
TIMESTAMP,FE,TDL,20190703113119,20190601000000,20190701000000,
TIMESTAMP,FE,KYMA,20190703113130,20190601000000,20190701000000,
TIMESTAMP,FE,UMRC,20190703113154,20190601000000,20190701000000,
TIMESTAMP,FE,MLW,20190703113211,20190601000000,20190701000000,
TIMESTAMP,FE,WOLF,20190703113221,20190601000000,20190701000000,
TIMESTAMP,FE,VEM,20190703113221,20190601000000,20190701000000,
TIMESTAMP,FE,ZER,20190703113154,20190601000000,20190701000000,
```

code:

```
Scanner prodScanner = new Scanner(prodFile);
     while (prodScanner.hasNextLine()) {
     String currentRecord = prodScanner.nextLine().trim(); 
                    if (currentRecord.length() > 0) {
                    prodRecordsFromStatement.add(currentRecord);
                  }
           }
Scanner nonProdScanner = new Scanner(nonProdFile);
while (nonProdScanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String currentRecord = nonProdScanner.nextLine().trim();  
            if (currentRecord.length() > 0) {                                   
     nonProdRecordsFromStatement.add(currentRecord);
                                }
                            }
Collection<String> result = new ArrayList<>(CollectionUtils.disjunction(prodRecordsFromStatement, nonProdRecordsFromStatement));
 List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<>(result);
 Collections.sort(resultList);
```

Actual Results:

```
TIMESTAMP,FE,KYMA,20190703113130,20190601000000,20190701000000,
TIMESTAMP,FE,KYMI,20190703113130,20190601000000,20190701000000,
TIMESTAMP,FE,MLI,20190703113211,20190601000000,20190701000000,
TIMESTAMP,FE,MLW,20190703113211,20190601000000,20190701000000,
TIMESTAMP,FE,TDI,20190703113119,20190601000000,20190701000000,
TIMESTAMP,FE,TDL,20190703113119,20190601000000,20190701000000,
TIMESTAMP,FE,UMRC,20190703113154,20190601000000,20190701000000,
TIMESTAMP,FE,UMRI,20190703113154,20190601000000,20190701000000,
TIMESTAMP,FE,WOLF,20190703113221,20190601000000,20190701000000,
TIMESTAMP,FE,WOLI,20190703113221,20190601000000,20190701000000,
```

Expected Results:
I want name of the file/list to be display for easy understanding

```
text2.txt,TIMESTAMP,FE,KYMA,20190703113130,20190601000000,20190701000000,
text1.txt,TIMESTAMP,FE,KYMI,20190703113130,20190601000000,20190701000000,
text1.txt,TIMESTAMP,FE,MLI,20190703113211,20190601000000,20190701000000,
text2.txt,TIMESTAMP,FE,MLW,20190703113211,20190601000000,20190701000000,
text1.txt,TIMESTAMP,FE,TDI,20190703113119,20190601000000,20190701000000,
text2.txt,TIMESTAMP,FE,TDL,20190703113119,20190601000000,20190701000000,
text2.txt,TIMESTAMP,FE,UMRC,20190703113154,20190601000000,20190701000000,
text1.txt,TIMESTAMP,FE,UMRI,20190703113154,20190601000000,20190701000000,
text2.txt,TIMESTAMP,FE,WOLF,20190703113221,20190601000000,20190701000000,
text1.txt,TIMESTAMP,FE,WOLI,20190703113221,20190601000000,20190701000000,
```

Comment: Maybe this would be useful:  https://github.com/java-diff-utils/java-diff-utils  There's a "DiffRowGenerator" in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through `resultList` checking to see if the current item is also in `prodRecordsFromStatement`.

If so, it's from file 1, otherwise it's from file 2.

Answer (score 1):

How performant does your solution need to be?  If performance is not super critical, and your lists are not long, then you could switch to using `subtract` instead of disjunction.

E.g.

```
Collection<String> resultProdRecords = new ArrayList<>(CollectionUtils.subtract(prodRecordsFromStatement, nonProdRecordsFromStatement));
Collection<String> resultNonProdRecords = new ArrayList<>(CollectionUtils.subtract(prodRecordsFromStatement, nonProdRecordsFromStatement));
```

`resultProdRecords` will contain all the lines from prodRecordsFromStatement that are not also in nonProdRecordFromStatement.

`resultNonProdRecords` will contain all the lines from nonProdRecordFromStatement that are not also in prodRecordsFromStatement.

Comment: I have duplicates in one of the list, so I cannot use subtract